# pandas average by timestamp and day of the week

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with the following format:

```
            ds                    sensor_id           measurement
0    2019-09-13 12:40:00             20053             0.916667           
1    2019-09-13 12:45:00             20053             0.583333           
2    2019-09-13 12:50:00             20053             0.733333   

....

2837 2019-09-23 17:20:00             20053             2.900000
```

What I want to do is generate a new data frame where the measurements are averaged for these 5 minute time blocks based on the day of the week. i.e. averaged over 5 minutes for every sunday, monday, tuesday and so on in the dataset and get this averaged dataframe for the whole week.

I know there are many functions to get the day  of week in pandas but I could not figure out how to use them to do this averaging.

Comment: Would your expected output have 7 values? one for each of the week

Comment: @ansev 7 days but for each of the 5 minute time stamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(2838),index=pd.date_range('2019-09-13 12:40:00', periods=2838, freq='5T'))

df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%A %H:%M')).mean()
```

Output:

```
                     0
Friday 00:00  0.992586
Friday 00:05  0.454352
Friday 00:10  0.747474
Friday 00:15  0.161208
Friday 00:20  0.422006
Friday 00:25  0.643614
Friday 00:30  0.450312
Friday 00:35  0.029722
Friday 00:40  0.316843
Friday 00:45  0.676068
...
Wednesday 23:10  0.424629
Wednesday 23:15  0.231609
Wednesday 23:20  0.987456
Wednesday 23:25  0.123619
Wednesday 23:30  0.203492
Wednesday 23:35  0.377411
Wednesday 23:40  0.131120
Wednesday 23:45  0.935324
Wednesday 23:50  0.910381
Wednesday 23:55  0.438193
```

Comment: The frame I have does not have the index set on the timestamp column. Is it necessary to change that?

Comment: No, you can use the .dt accesor and do the same thing.  `df.groupby(df['timecol'].dt.strftime....`

Comment: Did you see the `.dt.` between column and strftime?

Comment: I did but you saw it sooner! :)

Comment: One last question. Is it possible to still has the new index as a datetime data type. I know I will use the date part but I would still like to use it as a timestamp with the hour, minute, second and the date of the week information.

Comment: What does `%A` mean here ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, given the following input:

```
import numpy as np
date_range = pd.date_range('10/10/2019', periods=20, freq='Min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'measurement':np.random.randint(0, 100, len(date_range))}, index=date_range)

                     measurement
2019-10-10 00:00:00           13
2019-10-10 00:01:00           40
2019-10-10 00:02:00           86
............
............
2019-10-10 00:16:00           14
2019-10-10 00:17:00           89
2019-10-10 00:18:00           43
2019-10-10 00:19:00           96
```

try this code:

```
df.resample('5Min').mean()
```

and gives:

```
                     measurement
2019-10-10 00:00:00         69.2
2019-10-10 00:05:00         41.8
2019-10-10 00:10:00         26.4
2019-10-10 00:15:00         46.0
```

Comment: My index is not set to the timestamp column. Also, this does not aggregate by the day of the week, I think.

Answer (score -1):

extract day of week using the function you know from column ds and store in column "day_of_week", and similarly, extract time(I mean hour:minute:second) to another column "time". Then simply do:

```
orginal_df.groupby(["day_of_week", "time"]).mean()
```