# pandas change column type to datetime afterr group by

Tags: python, pandas

This is related to a previous question which I asked here ([pandas average by timestamp and day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330846/pandas-average-by-timestamp-and-day-of-the-week)).

Here, I perform a groupby operation as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(2838),index=pd.date_range('2019-09-13 12:40:00', periods=2838, freq='5T'))

# Reset the index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.groupby(df.index.dt.strftime('%A %H:%M')).mean()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Now if I check the data types of the column, we have:

```
index     object
0        float64
```

The column does not retain its datetime data type. How can I still preserve the column data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do grouping like that, instead, I would do double grouping/indexing:

```
days = df.index.day_name()
times = df.index.time

df.groupby([days,times]).mean()
```

which gives (head):

```
                        0
Friday 00:00:00  0.524322
       00:05:00  0.857684
       00:10:00  0.593461
       00:15:00  0.755158
       00:20:00  0.049511
```

where the first level index is the (string) day names, and second level index are `datetime` type.

Comment: Thank you! So following your suggestion, I did: `days = df['ds'].dt.dayofweek
    times = df['ds'].dt.time`. Now, if I want to get all the records for say a Sunday (weekday 0) how can I go about it from this structure?

Comment: `new_df.loc[0]`?